# How can I add slide show feature to this code?

Tags: processing, slideshow

Hello everybody I am new in processing so I am trying to play around,I found this code https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/437870 and I am trying to find a way how can I add multiple images.So that when I do mouseWheel() image changes .I found this other code https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/48114/# for slide show also but I couldn't figure out how to merge them together .I would be glad if you could help me.

Comment: Hello! Please post the relevant code in your question as the link's content may be modified or removed in the future (every question also functions as an archive for future reference). And about your question, the key will be to load your images in an array or ArrayList (which I prefer), and to compartiment the original code to be able to cycle through them. How competent with programming are you? Can you use class? (I'm asking so I don't provide an answer which is too complicated to be useful)

Comment: Sorry for that,it is my first time posting.I am not great at programming yet.I know classes in CSS if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not proficient with CSS so I'm not sure about your skill level as a programmer, but the examples you provided were working with class, so it's how we'll proceed. And here's the kind of result that we'll get:

[image: Cycling]

First, we must solve the problem, then we can code it through. Here's what I thing is how we should proceed:

1. Create a class to keep the pixelized images data.
2. Initialize the program with all the images you want.
3. Adapt the `draw()` loop to the new architecture.
4. Create a method to cycle the images.

I'll mostly recycle the existing code, but in a way which let us get what you want.

---

#### Create a class to keep the pixelized images data

This class will need the following functionalities:

- An ArrayList of Particles.
- A method to load an image and transform it into Particles.
- A Render method.

Here's how we'll accomplish this:

```
class PixelizedImage {
  // Here's an arrayList for the Particles
  ArrayList<Particle> particles = new ArrayList<Particle>();

  // the constructor will transform the image in a particle Array, no need to have a special method
  public PixelizedImage(PImage img) {
    img.loadPixels();

    for (int y = 0; y < img.height; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < img.width; x++) {
        int loc = x + y * img.width;
        color pixelColor = img.pixels[loc];

        if (alpha(pixelColor) == 0) { 
          continue;
        }
        if (loc % 8 > 0) { 
          continue;
        }
        if (y % 8 != 0) {
          continue;
        }

        Particle pixel = new Particle(x+(width-img.width)/2, y+(height-img.height)/2, pixelColor);
        particles.add(pixel);
        pixel.display();
      }
    }
  }

  // Render() will draw the pixelized image
  public void Render() {
    for (Particle particle : particles) {
      if (mousePressed) {
        PVector force = a.attract(particle);
        a.update();
        particle.applyForce(force);
      } else {
        particle.arrive();
      }
      particle.update();
      particle.display();
    }
  }
}
```

For a beginner this may look somewhat complex, but I assure you that I mostly recycled the code you linked to. The part which need skill here is to know what to recycle and where to use it, and once you get the hang of reading code you'll be able to do this quite easily.

---

#### Initialize the program with all the images you want

Of course, methods like `setup()` and `draw()`, and the global variables, will have to be updated to follow the new architecture.

First, the global variables: we don't need them all. Here's what we need now:

```
// an arrayList of PixelizedImage to keep them at hand
ArrayList<PixelizedImage> images = new ArrayList<PixelizedImage>();
// the index of the image currently displayed
int currentDisplay = 0;
// variables needed by the surviving original code
Attractor a;
int pixelStep = 5;
```

The `setup()` method is for initializing things before the program's main loop starts. That's where we'll load our images:

```
void setup() {
  // size of the window and attractor for the original code
  size(800, 600); 
  a = new Attractor();

  // initializing all the images and storing them in the 'images' ArrayList
  for (String s : new String[] {"1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png", "6.png"}) {
    images.add(new PixelizedImage(loadImage(s)));
  }
}
```

We are now ready to work on actually showing and cycling through these images!

---

#### Adapt the `draw()` loop to the new architecture

The `draw()` loop run about 60 times per second (unless you change the FPS or your machine is slow). It can do whatever you want, and in our case it'll just paint the images, so it'll be short enough:

```
void draw() {
  background(0);
  noStroke();

  // knowing the index of the current image, we fish it out of the ArrayList and draw it
  images.get(currentDisplay).Render();
}
```

Almost finished!

---

#### Create a method to cycle the images

We need a way to cycle through our images. It could be on click (but the attractor makes this less interesting), linked to the mousewheel as you said, linked to a key or something like that. Because it's easy and straightforward, we'll use the space bar:

```
void keyPressed() {
  // if the key actually being pressed makes a ' ' character:
  if (key == ' ') {
    currentDisplay++;
    if (currentDisplay >= images.size()) {
      currentDisplay = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Simple enough, right? If you followed through, you should have a working program by now. Try it! Don't forget to include the 2 class which came with your example (I'm copying the code here in case the source gets removed or something like this in the future, but note that I made exactly ZERO change to this code):

```
class Particle {
  PVector pos;
  PVector vel;
  PVector acc;
  PVector target;
  color pixelColor;
  int mass;
  float maxVel;
  float maxforce;

  Particle(int x, int y, color inputColor) {
    pos = new PVector(x, y);
    target = new PVector(x, y);
    vel = new PVector(0, 0);
    acc = new PVector(0, 0);
    pixelColor = inputColor;
    mass = 1;
    maxVel = 20;
    maxforce = 1.5;
  }

  void applyForce(PVector force) {
    acc.add(force);
  }

  void arrive() {
    PVector desired = PVector.sub(target, pos);  // A vector pointing from the position to the target
    float d = desired.mag();
    // Scale with arbitrary damping within 100 pixels
    if (d < 100) {
      float m = map(d, 0, 100, 0, maxVel);
      desired.setMag(m);
    } else {
      desired.setMag(maxVel);
    }

    // Steering = Desired minus Velocity
    PVector steer = PVector.sub(desired, vel);
    steer.limit(maxforce);  // Limit to maximum steering force
    applyForce(steer);
  }

  void update() {
    vel.add(acc);
    vel.limit(maxVel);
    pos.add(vel);
    acc.mult(0);
  }

  void display() {
    fill(pixelColor);
    ellipse(pos.x, pos.y, pixelStep, pixelStep);
  }
}

class Attractor {
  PVector position; 
  float mass;
  float G;

  Attractor() {
    position = new PVector(width/2, height/2);
    mass = 20;
    G = 1;
  }

  PVector attract(Particle p) {
    PVector force = PVector.sub(position, p.pos);
    float d = force.mag();
    d = constrain(d, 2, 6);
    force.normalize();
    float strength = (G * mass * p.mass) / (d * d);
    force.mult(strength);      
    return force;
  }

  void update() {
    position.x = mouseX;
    position.y = mouseY;
  }

  void display() {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    ellipse(position.x, position.y, 16, 16);
  }
}
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you very much!   I have been trying to figure it out for couple of days already.
I followed as you said and it is working perfectly You're the best!

Comment: @laancelot That is very well explained and thorough answer (+1)